# JSon to WebAPI becomes [[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]

Tags: asp.net-web-api

something strange is happening with my WebAPI that I can't seem to figure out yet.
I'm using SoapUI to post this payload:

```
{
'Id': '00000000-0000-0000-1821-000000000000',
'Operation': 'post',
'Severity': 1,
'LoginName': 'nickj@noemail.email',
'EventText': 'testing post method'
}
```

My WebAPI is just this:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage PostTrackingInformation(HttpRequestMessage req)
    {
        var content = req.Content;
        string jsonContent = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
```

However, when I look at the string content, I end up with content that looks like this:

```
[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]]
```

I am sending in application/json as the Content-Type

Has anybody seen this before?  What am I missing?
Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Is there a reason why you include `HttpRequestMessage` as the parameter? It can be accessed in the controller method by using `this.Request`. Usually you would use `public HttpResponseMessage PostTrackingInformation(TrackingInfo info)` where `TrackingInfo` is the class that is represented by your JSON - without the need to read the payload from the request yourself.

Comment: I was doing it that way.  With the class name in there.  But I've also ran into issues where the class didn't map out the way I needed to in the JSON.    So I do it explicitly now, not implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to not be an issue with the API itself, but with Restsharp 106.69's version and Newtonsoft.

I ended up adding this package:

> using RestSharp.Serializers.Newtonsoft.Json;

and then my Restsharp Request lines like this:

> var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest {Method =
>   Method.POST, RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json, JsonSerializer = new
>   NewtonsoftJsonSerializer()};

It also sounds like the next major version of RestSharp (107) will support Newtonsoft Again.